OCR Multiline Text Splicing
I built my own OCR recognition model to recognize text in images and then translate them, but found that the recognized text is all line text and coordinates. How can I determine if these multiple lines of text are a segment of text?[enter image description here](henter image description herettps://i.sstatic.net/651d1MlB.jpg)
How should I concatenate these multiple lines of text, otherwise translating them line by line would result in poor results.
